# How to find equation for curve given a point that it passes through?

Tags: calculus

Find an equation of the curve passing through the point $(1, 5)$ and having a slope $\sin(x)+x$ every point.

I tried $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$ formula, and got $y-5=m(x-1)$, for $x = 5$. I then put the x value into the $\sin(x)+x$ formula, and got $\frac{\sin(5)}{5}$.

I tried submitting the answer and it says that's wrong. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

If the slope of a function $F(x)$ is $f(x)$, what is $F(x)$? (Hint: Think about derivatives). Note that an indefinite integral has an arbitrary constant associated with it. Could the point you are given allow you to identify the particular function from this entire family of functions?

Answer (score 0):

The slope changes depending on where you are on the graph, it is not linear, since the rate of change does not depend in a constant way on your position along the curve.

Parametrize the curve:
$\gamma(t)=(1,5)+t(1,\sin(t)+t)=(1+t,5+t\sin(t)+t^2)$ for some $t\in \mathbb{R}$. It is then clear that your rate of change (ratio between $y$ and $x$ coordinate is $\frac{\sin(t)+t}{1}=\frac{y}{x}$